# Подскажите админ панель для Laravel на React

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Подскажите, существует ли админ панель для Laravel на React? Есть [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/), но она сделана на VueJS. Хотелось бы использовать такую панель как основу для создания собственной админ панели.

Comment: бесплатные, даже если существуют - стоит подумать использзовать или нет. Сам активно использую [KeenThemes Metronic](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/)

Comment: Лучше написать свою, если знаешь реакт то пхп

Comment: @Pavel8289, написать свой велосипед я всегда могу. Меня интересует что-то готовое, более профессиональное - в том плане, что не поделка одиночки, а штука, которая прошла развитие и "созрела". Подойдет даже платный вариант.